# Huge CPU impact LinkedBlockingQueue

Tags: java, multithreading, load, cpu

I have a `LinkedBlockingQueue` called `tasks`, but when I call `tasks.take()` and wait for a task to become available, the CPU usage is 100%. I've got multiple threads using the `tasks.take()` method (every thread has its own `tasks` variable). Does anybody know why this is happening?

*Defenition of the `tasks` variable*

```
private LinkedBlockingQueue<ComputerTask> tasks;
// snip
this.tasks = new LinkedBlockingQueue<ComputerTask>(100);
```

*Code to take a task*

```
ComputerTask task = tasks.take();
```

*Code to offer a new task*

```
this.tasks.offer(task);
```

P.S. I don't know if this is a problem with my version of Java, cause I haven't tested it on any other computers yet.

```
java version "1.6.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_31-b04-413-11M3623)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.6-b01-413, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Presumably, nothing is pushing tasks and the queue is empty, yes?  If so, and it's definitely the consumer threads that are looping,  it sure sounds broke!

Comment: Yes. The queue is empty, it's not filled up like every 0.2 sec or so. Could last several minutes before it gets filled up again. Is that an issue then, the emptyness? It however is a crucial part of the program, so I can't really take it out. Any recommendations?

Comment: @Robbietjuh I recommend you do some more evaluations of where the increased CPU is.  For example, have 10 threads just sit on take without any producers at all.  If that still shows a CPU increase you have an issue somewhere else (to prove this write a simple app that does the same thing with no other functionality).  If you are using standard JDK and are simply `take`ing on a LBQ there will be no CPU useage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a `LinkedBlockingQueue` called tasks, but when I call `tasks.take()` and wait for a task to become available, the CPU usage is 100%. I've got multiple threads using the `tasks.take()` method (every thread has its own tasks variable).

`tasks.take();` should not be spinning unless it is dequeuing a large number of items.  If the queue is empty, it will block so I suspect this is *not* the cause of the 100% load.  I would make sure you use a profiler or add debug statements around the `take()` to see if it is being called some large number of times.

One thing to remember is that `tasks.offer(task)` returns `false` immediately if the queue is full.  I'm wondering you should be using `tasks.put(task)` which will block instead and not spin.  If you are using `offer()` to determine which task handler to run the task on, then maybe you are looping around and around when all of the task handlers' queues are full?

If you are doing your own task management, you might consider using instead one of the built-in `ExecutorService` classes.  You then can submit all of your tasks or use a blocking queue and the `ExecutorService` will handle feeding each thread in the pool its tasks:

```
// start 10 threads handling the tasks
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
// now submit tasks to the pools that will be run with the 10 threads
threadPool.submit(task);
...
```

In the above example `ComputerTask` has to implement `Runnable`.

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into it. One thing I'd like to say is that the queues will never get full, there aren't enough tasks to do so. And if they do - there's serious bug going around.